# Cut elimination proofs of the consistency of arithmetic

Tags: logic, proof-theory

It is well known that one can use cut elimination to establish the consistency of arithmetic (though this involves assuming transfinite induction up to a particular countable ordinal.) Most proofs, however, work within an infinitary system with an omega rule. Are there any proofs of cut elimination in arithmetic that avoid this, and that just work using only the ordinary rules of first-order logic, without the omega-rule? I'm happy to have induction etc. formulated as rules, rather than axioms, if that makes a difference.

Comment: What specifically seems unclear?

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Kumar I'm not sure what rephrasing you're looking for. This question does in fact have serious technical prerequisites, and to me it seems well-written given those. Not all questions need to be entirely self-contained.

Comment: @dantopa See my comment to Kumar.

Comment: Takeuti's book does it in plain sequent calculus without the $\omega$ rule if I recall correctly.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I will check out Takeuti, thanks.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Maybe you are correct. Can you please provide an answer to the above question? I would love to read it. :)